# Clarifying A Javascript Function (or Method?)

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS, that is to say I've had about 2 and a half days of experience.

There is a piece of code I don't quite understand and would appreciate a clarification.

```
confirmPassword.oninput = () => checkPassword(confirmPassword.value);
```

I can make sense of what is happening here, kind of, but not entirely.

The  `= () =>` confuses me a bit.

Comment: [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

It's doing this:

```js
confirmPassword.oninput = function() {
    checkPassword(confirmPassword.value);
}
```